# Why is my modifier limiting user registrations to 2 only?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

My contract is working just fine on compilation and deployment over Remix but when I run it after deployment otherwise, the number of user registrations is getting limited to 2.

I tried a lot of tweaks in the contract, used different environments and local machines, versions and what not and still the issue persists. Here is the code for reference:

```
/* Modifier is checking for candidates register ones only for the same address*/
modifier onlyones (address _numberid) 
{
require(_numberid != admin, "Admin and Candidate have the same Address"); 
uint count = 0;
if (candidates.length >= 1) 
{
for (uint i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++)
{
if (candidates[i].numberid == _numberid) {
count = count + 1;}
}
}
require (count<=1 && candidates.length <= 1, "Invalid Doubled Registration");
```

[image: image of code]

Comment: Perhaps you would like to properly indent your code and then delete the redundant screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

In this line : `require (count<=1 && candidates.length <= 1, "Invalid Doubled Registration")`, you are checking two conditions:

- count should be less than or equal to 1.
- The length of the candidates array should also be less than or equal to 1.

If either of these conditions is not met, the contract execution will stop and the error message "Invalid Doubled Registration" will be returned.

So in your case you may want to only check that candidates have one registration : `require (count<=1, "Invalid Doubled Registration")`
No need to look at the length of candidates array.